# qml: Reference Error: cant find variable

Tags: qml

I have 15 roles for my ListModel. I am not specifying all of them for every ListElement because they are not always required.

I have common code for displaying values based on roles.
So if my current ListElement doesnt have role `a` defined, and I'm trying to check for that value, it throws a reference error.

I tried to catch this error using `(a==undefined || a== null)` but it still throws a reference error on `a`.

Is there any other option to catch this error? (except for writing all roles for all ListElements)

Answer (score 1):

For convenience model roles available as delegate's properties (as you do currently). You can access them with the qualified model name instead. E.g. `model.a` instead of just `a`. If a role is not available value of expression will be undefined, but it's not an error. Typical work around is to use boolean operators, e.g. `model.a || "default value"`.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
if (a) {
  // Your stuff here
}
```